# Get the next process id instance with Jmeter tool

Tags: jmeter, postman, rest, jbpm

I am using JMeter tool to send some rest API request to jBPM. I use this post request to create  process instances in JBPM with JMeter:
[image]

This one creates two process instances with id 1 and another process instance with id 2.

I use this one to extract the `process instance id = 1`:

[image]

I use this one to get and exctract the task id:
[image]
[image]

How can I modify the JMeter tool to extract only the second process id, for example in my case to extract the `process instance id=2`? I tried to add +1 in the Regular Expression but it didn't work. I tried it with postman also and this configuration I made only works if I extract the second process instance id, because only the second one have data's like this:

```
{
  "task-summary" : [ {
    "task-id" : 2,
    "task-name" : "Task",
    "task-subject" : "",
    "task-description" : "",
    "task-status" : "Reserved",
    "task-priority" : 0,
    "task-is-skipable" : false,
    "task-actual-owner" : "wbadmin",
    "task-created-by" : null,
    "task-created-on" : {
  "java.util.Date" : 1622815612000
},
    "task-activation-time" : {
  "java.util.Date" : 1622815612000
},
    "task-expiration-time" : null,
    "task-proc-inst-id" : 64,
    "task-proc-def-id" : "performance-samples.paralleltasks",
    "task-container-id" : "performance-samples_1.0.0",
    "task-parent-id" : -1,
    "correlation-key" : "64",
    "process-type" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Every time i start a process with POST request it will always create two process instances. If i run it again it will create process instances with id 3 and 4 and if i run it again it will create process instances with id 5 and 6. So, every time i need to extract the second process id, e.g. id 2, 3, 4 and so on. So, also putting try match no. 2 wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot help without seeing full response including what do you want to extract.

One thing is obvious: [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4017) therefore using regular expressions for parsing it is not the best idea.

JMeter provides [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) designed for working with JSON so there is much more convenient, robust, reliable and powerful way of getting the data out of JSON responses, filtering it, running various functions, etc.